# asyncio queue collecting coroutine's return values

Tags: python, queue, return-value, python-asyncio

I have a clickhouse database in which I would like to execute asynchronous queries, each on different node. 
I found example on https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-queue.html#examples as what I need.
I modified it a bit (see bellow) and it works, but...

```
from aioch import Client

result_set = []


async def exec_sql(name, queue, client):
    while True:
        print('name =',name)
        sql = await queue.get()
        result_set.append(await client.execute(sql))
        # Notify the queue that the "work item" has been processed.
        queue.task_done()

async def main():
    num_of_nodes = 10
    num_of_sqls = 20

    ports = range(2441, 2451)

    clients = [Client(host='localhost', port=port, database='database', compression=True) for port in ports]


    # Create a queue that we will use to store our "workload".
    queue = asyncio.Queue()

    # Generate sql's
    for _ in range(num_of_sqls):
        sql = 'select hostName()'
        queue.put_nowait(sql)

    # Create worker tasks to process the queue concurrently.
    tasks = []
    for i in range(num_of_nodes):
        task = asyncio.create_task(exec_sql(f'worker-{i}', queue, clients[i]))
        tasks.append(task)

    # Wait until the queue is fully processed.
    await queue.join()

    # Cancel our worker tasks.
    for task in tasks:
        task.cancel()
    # Wait until all worker tasks are cancelled.
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks, return_exceptions=True)

asyncio.run(main())

print(result_set)
```

Is there a better way for collecting results of each query than defining an empty array "result_set" at the very beginning?

Comment: Ever figured out how to get the results through gather ?

Answer (score -1):

you should be able to return the awaited execution right there.. that way it's all stitched together on gather.. i.e.

```
async def exec_sql(name, queue, client):
  while True:
    print('name =',name)
    sql = await queue.get()
    result = await client.execute(sql)
    # Notify the queue that the "work item" has been processed.
    queue.task_done()
    return result
```